# How can I verify CAN message ID received in CANoe against DBC file using CAPL?

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I did similar with message DLC using predefined function ChkCreate_InconsistentDLC. Looking for options to do the same for message ID.

I have been trying to find some predefined function.

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? Occurrence of a message? Count of messages? Absence of a message?

Comment: I think the CAPL function doesn't exist because the test doesn't make sense. How would you check for an incorrect message ID since message ID is indeed the thing used to identify what you've received? How could you receive a message, look at the ID, and then determine whether the ECU intended to or was supposed to send a different message ID?